# Asp.Net MVC 4 Form Field as Url ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a search form (method: GET) on asp.net mvc 4.

**There's my form:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Questions", "Article", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="order" value="Desc" />
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />
            }
```

I need pass input value (#id) as route id.

**There's my route:**

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**And my Action:**

```
public ActionResult Questions(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Pretending my controller is called **Stackoverflow** and my action **Question** i need the url be:

localhost:port/Stackoverflow/Questions/(#id [input-value])

**localhost:port/Stackoverflow/Questions/MVC**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not using a Model for your form, you will need to read the ID from the HttpContext on the get action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Questions(string id)
{
    string _id = Request.Form["id"];
}
```

You might want to redirect at this point with your id.

```
return RedirectToAction("DoSomethingWithId", _id);
```